# python replace value string with number

Tags: python

im building a system to sort some .log files in .txt format so that I later can send it to excel. There is 70+ files and in every file im scanning for a keyword, I get 1000+ strings that I want to save in a .txt. I can get every string that I want and see from which .log file each log has ben taken, but now I want to rename the file that the .log came from with a corresponding number 1,2,3,4,5...(one number for every file instead for its file name). code:

```
import glob


def LogFile(filename, tester):
    message = []
    data = []
    print(filename)

    with open(filename) as filesearch:   # open search file
        filesearch = filesearch.readlines()   # read file

    i = 1
    d = {}
    for filename in filename:
        if not d.get(filename, False):
            d[filename] = i
            i += 1

    for line in filesearch:
        if tester in line:   # extract ""
            start = '-> '
            end = ':\ '
            number = line[line.find(start)+3: line.find(end)]        #[ord('-> '):ord(' :\ ')]
            data.append(number)   # store all found wors in array
            text = line[line.find(end)+3:]
            message.append(text)

    with open('Msg.txt', 'a') as handler:  # create .txt file
        for i in range(len(data)):
            handler.write(f"{i}|{data[i]}|{message[i]}")

# open with 'w' to "reset" the file.
with open('Msg.txt', 'w') as file_handler:
    pass
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------


for filename in glob.glob(r'C:\Users\FKAISER\Desktop\AccessSPA\SPA\*.log'):
    LogFile(filename, 'Sending Request: Tester')
```

I have tried using this function

```
i = 1
d = {}
for filename in filename:
    if not d.get(filename, False):
        d[filename] = i
        i += 1
```

but then it looks like this

[image]

i want each file to have the same number as in the picture, 1 indicates for all the 26 logs and 2 indicates for the 10 file in that folder... etc

Comment: `for filename in filename:` hmmmmm

Comment: yeah I know, strange... but I don´t get anything else to work either

Comment: what is the output if you `print(filename)`  before calling the `LogFile` function?

Comment: unresolved reference